# Why does my Pytorch tensor size change and contain NaNs after some batches?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, speech-recognition, nan

I am Training a Pytorch model. After some time, even if on shuffle, the model contains, besides a few finite tensorrows only NaN values:

```
tensor([[[    nan,     nan,     nan,  ...,     nan,     nan,     nan],
         [    nan,     nan,     nan,  ...,     nan,     nan,     nan],
         [    nan,     nan,     nan,  ...,     nan,     nan,     nan],
         ...,
         [ 1.4641,  0.0360, -1.1528,  ..., -2.3592, -2.6310,  6.3893],
         [    nan,     nan,     nan,  ...,     nan,     nan,     nan],
         [    nan,     nan,     nan,  ...,     nan,     nan,     nan]]],
       device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

The detect_anomaly functions return:

```
  File "TestDownload.py", line 701, in <module>
    main(learning_rate, batch_size, epochs, experiment)
  File "TestDownload.py", line 635, in main
    train(model, device, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, epoch, iter_meter, experiment)
  File "TestDownload.py", line 486, in train
    output = F.log_softmax(output, dim=2)
  File "\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1672, in log_softmax
    ret = input.log_softmax(dim)
 (function _print_stack) Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestDownload.py", line 701, in <module>
    main(learning_rate, batch_size, epochs, experiment)
  File "TestDownload.py", line 635, in main
    train(model, device, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, epoch, iter_meter, experiment)
  File "TestDownload.py", line 490, in train
    loss.backward()
  File "\lib\site-packages\comet_ml\monkey_patching.py", line 317, in wrapper
    return_value = original(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py", line 245, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
  File "\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", line 145, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
RuntimeError: Function 'LogSoftmaxBackward' returned nan values in its 0th output.
```

in reference to the next line `output = F.log_softmax(output, dim=2)`

It shows another error if I just do it with try-except: (when the loss function is running on a tensor containing NaNs)

```
[W ..\torch\csrc\autograd\python_anomaly_mode.cpp:104] Warning: Error detected in CtcLossBackward. Traceback of forward call that caused the error:
  File "TestDownload.py", line 734, in <module>
    # In[ ]:
  File "TestDownload.py", line 667, in main
    test(model, device, test_loader, criterion, epoch, iter_meter, experiment)
  File "TestDownload.py", line 517, in train
    loss.backward()
  File "\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 1590, in forward
    return F.ctc_loss(log_probs, targets, input_lengths, target_lengths, self.blank, self.reduction,
  File "\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2307, in ctc_loss
    return torch.ctc_loss(
 (function _print_stack)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestDownload.py", line 518, in train
  File "\lib\site-packages\comet_ml\monkey_patching.py", line 317, in wrapper
    return_value = original(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py", line 245, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
  File "\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", line 145, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
RuntimeError: Function 'CtcLossBackward' returned nan values in its 0th output.
```

A normal tensor should look like this:

```
tensor([[[-3.3904, -3.4340, -3.3703,  ..., -3.3613, -3.5098, -3.4344]],

        [[-3.3760, -3.2948, -3.2673,  ..., -3.4039, -3.3827, -3.3919]],

        [[-3.3857, -3.3358, -3.3901,  ..., -3.4686, -3.4749, -3.3826]],

        ...,

        [[-3.3568, -3.3502, -3.4416,  ..., -3.4463, -3.4921, -3.3769]],

        [[-3.4379, -3.3508, -3.3610,  ..., -3.3707, -3.4030, -3.4244]],

        [[-3.3919, -3.4513, -3.3565,  ..., -3.2714, -3.3984, -3.3643]]],
       device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<TransposeBackward0>)
```

*Please notice the double brackets, if they are import.*

Code:

```py
for batch_idx, _data in enumerate(train_loader):
    spectrograms, labels, input_lengths, label_lengths = _data
    spectrograms, labels = spectrograms.to(device), labels.to(device)
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    output = model(spectrograms)
    output = F.log_softmax(output, dim=2)
    output = output.transpose(0, 1)  # (time, batch, n_class) # X, 1, 29
    loss = criterion(output, labels, input_lengths, label_lengths)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()
    iter_meter.step()
```

Additionally, I tried to run it with a bigger batch size (current batch size:1, bigger batch size: 6) and it run without errors until 40% of the first epoch in which I got this error.

> Cuda run out of memory

Also, I tried to normalize the data `torchaudio.transforms.MelSpectrogram(sample_rate=16000, n_mels=128, normalized=True)`

And reducing the learning rate from 5e-4 to 5e-5 did not help either.

Additional information: My dataset contains nearly 300000 .wav files and the error came at 3-10% runtime in the first epoch.

I appreciate any hints and I will gladly submit further information.

Comment: Hello, the 4 lines of code you posted are not enough to help, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and add the whole stacktrace as well, not just the last entry. Finally, the NaN and cuda-oom issues are most likely two distinct issues in your code

Comment: You're right, but I didn't know what else to show. Since it is a machine learning model it is not easily reproducible. I got the code from assemblyai, here is the [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IPpwx4rX32rqHKpLz7dc8sOKspUa-YKO). I'll edit my question and add the whole stack trace.

Comment: for the out-of-memory, you can run `nvidia-smi -l 1` while your model is training in order to monitor the gpu memory usage. If it is increasing linearly with time, you have a problem in your code. If it doesnt, you just need to ajust your batch_size. For the NaN issue I really need to see the model, but first try to skim it. Make the smallest possible model that reproduces your error, removing layer after layer

Comment: Thanks for the code. I run and looked up for any difference between 1000th and 10000th batch and there was none. I tried to run it differently, without continue statements if the output contained NaN, and got `RuntimeError: Function 'CtcLossBackward' returned nan values in its 0th output.` (I edited my question for whole stack trace and added more code). So I guess I should not use my output if it's containing NaNs. I also tested if something was wrong with the input, but if I just skip the first batches until 15007th (error point) it works fine until some when later with the same error.

Comment: Have you checked that your are never feeding a bad input (i.e a batch with NaNs) in your network ? Maybe one of them is corrupted in some way

Comment: Well, I wrote `if not torch.all(output.isfinite()): continue`  so it checks output (`output = model(spectrograms)`). I don't know how I can check the input (the spectrograms and labels), I searched a lot but I guess I can only check the tensor. 
That the input is corrupted seems very logical, on the other hand does the model work if I skip the first batches until the error.

Comment: Also, It worked with a non-custom Dataset. So the code itself is not wrong or bad, I guess. It's more about my input but I don't know how to check it.

Comment: to check that your inputs are clean, iterate over your dataset (no need to train) and for each tensor `sample`, check the value of `sample.isnan().any()`. This will return true iff the tensor contains at least 1 NaN value.

Comment: Hey, I double checked the labels and something was wrong with them. Thanks for your help! If you want you can leave an answer (maybe just your last comment), so I can mark it as an answer and you'll get the green check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source of error can be a corrupted input or label, which would contain a NaN of inf value.
You can check that there is no NaN value in a tensor with

```
torch.isnan(tensor).any()
```

Or that all values in a tensor are neither `inf` nor `NaN` with

```
torch.isfinite(tensor).all()
```